# How to trigger my subscribeHook when Zapier zap is on

Tags: integration, webhooks, zapier

I completed the Subscribe Hook settings for the trigger I started creating for my own application. I think I have to make a change in Perform section for this Subscribe hook request to go whenever the Zap is On. But I have no idea exactly how to do it.

```
    const data = {
    url: bundle.targetUrl,
    style: bundle.inputData.style
  };

    const options = {
      url: '<my-url>',
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    
    }
    
      return z.request(options)
        .then((response) => JSON.parse(response.content));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add that function to your trigger definition under the `performSubscribe` property. There's example code [here](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform/blob/1360dff80a3512b88be52457991c579d2fa72e44/example-apps/rest-hooks/triggers/recipe.js#L93-L94).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I think there was a problem with the sample data I gave. I took care of it later. And also I just filled the subscribe hook url to text field without changing this code settings.